# Not possible to drop table, not possible to check open connections

Tags: postgresql

I am connected to the `postgres` database, as `postgres` user:

```
docker exec -it mycontainer psql -h localhost -U postgres
```

I see the databases:

```
postgres=# \l
                                 List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges

-----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+--------------------
---
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 srdb      | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =Tc/postgres       
  +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgr
es+
           |          |          |            |            | sruser=CTc/postgres
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres        
  +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgr
es
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres        
  +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgr
es
(4 rows)
```

I want to drop a table, but nothing happens:

```
postgres=# DROP DATABASE srdb
```

Maybe somebody else is connected? Let's check:

```
postgres-# SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity
```

Nothing!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

SQL statements may span multiple lines, so you need to mark the end of your statement with a semi-colon `;` (or the less-used metacommand `\g`)

Your `DROP DATABASE srdb` was not sent to the server and neither was the `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity`, as far as psql is concerned, it's an unfinished single statement. Also notice how the prompt `-#` on the second line differs from the `=#` of the first line: it's a secondary prompt indicating a continuation of the input, see [Prompting in psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PROMPTING).

Comment: I had tried with and without semicolon. No luck